# Posgresql: How to get values that have been replaced by keys id in another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, recursive-query

I have 2 tables with database like below. The column name in table A are replaced by id of table B

```
Match
id  my_member_id    your_member_id  date    score
1       2                   4       ...     ...
2       3                   4       ...     ...
3       1                   3       ...     ...
4       2                   3       ...     ...

Team
id          member_name
1               A
2               B
3               C
4               D
```

I want result like below:

```
Table Versus
date    my_member   your_member score
...         B           D       ...
...         C           D       ...
...         A           C       ...
...         B           C       ...
```

My query is taking forever to execute so I think it's wrong in somewhere

```
WITH RECURSIVE my_team AS
(
    SELECT m.id, t.member_name AS my_member
    FROM Team t INNER JOIN Match m ON t.id = m.id
),
your_team AS
(
    SELECT id, my_member, ''::TEXT AS your_member
    FROM my_team 
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT mt.id, mt.my_member, cte.your_member
    FROM my_team mt INNER JOIN your_team cte ON mt.id = cte.id
)
SELECT date, my_member, your_member, score
FROM Match m INNER JOIN your_team yt at ON m.id = yt.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need recursion for this.

Join into `team` twice, using aliases:

```
select m.date, my.member_name as my_member, y.member_name as your_member, m.score
  from match m
  join team my on my.id = m.my_member_id
  join team y on y.id = m.your_member_id;
```

Comment: Sorry but it is possible to write it by using CTE? Your answer is simple and clear but I wonder what it look like cause I'm trying to solve this in different ways

Comment: @CSKR  I am sorry, but this query is a poor candidate for using CTEs since it is a straightforward join.  I cannot think of how to solve this using recursion or even just straight CTEs.